# Why does Google Analytics report 100% bounce rate when the page has lots of page views?

Tags: google-analytics, bounce-rate, bounce

Google Analytics reports 100% bounce rate for a page which has lots of page views and an Avg Time on Page of 32 seconds. Shouldn't one of the following be true?

Either the bounce rate is less than 100% when the Avg Time on Page is greater than 0 or the Avg Time on Page is 0 when the bounce rate is 100%.

I fail to see how or why the report does not conform the above two conditions.

[image: Google Analytics 100 percent bounce rate]

Comment: None of the answers address this simple question. Let me rephrase: how GA knows an average time on page if all the users have only been in 1 page (therefore the cookie has not been hit twice)?

Answer (score 6):

A bounce occurs when a visitor looks at the page and then leaves the site, ie. doesn't go through to another internal page.

This would happen all the time if you had a 1 page website.

Another cause may be that you have very few call to actions drawing users to other pages, or your page gives them all the info they need so they don't need to go to another page.

It's hard to say without seeing the page in question.

Comment: +1 for defining bounce rate. many do not know, or do not care, what it actually means or what the difference is between a bounce and exit. More infomation about bounce here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009409?hl=en and exits here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2525491?hl=en&ref_topic=1120718 ...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about why the average time on page can be above 0 while the bounce rate is 100% though. (especially if you see how GA calculates tim on site: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006253?hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

The reason for that is the way Google calculates bounce rate, and how it represents the totals per page.

First look at this explanation of bounce rate: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2525491?hl=en

> For **all sessions that start with the page**, Bounce Rate is the percentage that were the only one of the session.
>
> Bounce Rate for a page is based **only on sessions that start with that page**.

So that means that in your analytics per page overview, a number of pageviews are not eligible for bounce rate calculation (but are eligible for avg time on page calculation).

It's best shown by this breakdown here:
[image]

As you can see in the top row, there are 5 unique pageviews for that page with a bounce rate of 100%. 
When we look at the breakdown per "Previous Page Path", we can see that actually only 1 of those 5 unique pageviews has a bounce rate of 100%. The other 4 have bounce rate 0%, and are not counted in the page's total bounce rate calculation. That's because neither of those 4 were the first page in the session, and thus not eligible for bounce rate calculation.

Contrary to bounce rate, all those unique pageviews do contribute to the Avg. time on page, thus giving the strange summary in the top row of 100% bounce rate and 00:00:31 Avg time on page.

Answer (score 1):

If your page links only to other web pages or to files on your own server, there will likely be a 100% bounce rate.  If a user clicks to download a file, this isn't tracked by default.  Also, if your page links to other pages, they are bouncing from your page to go to these new pages.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that lots of visitors come to a single page and leaves your website, that is why it shows 100% bounce rate.

Answer (score 1):

If persistent cookies can not be set, each pageview will be counted as a new 'Session' and your bounce rate will be 100% and pageviews/visit will be 1.